# why my c++ code to find factorials is not working?

Tags: c++, debugging

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, t;
    cin >> n;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> t;
        int arr[200];
        arr[0] = 1;
        int j;
        for(j = 1; j < 200; j++) arr[j] = 0;
        int l = 1, k;
        for(j = 1; j <= t; j++){
            int rem = 0, flag = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < l; k++){
                int temp = (arr[k]*j) ;
                arr[k] = (temp + rem) % 10;
                rem = (temp+rem) / 10;
                if(k == l-1 && rem != 0){
                    arr[l] = rem;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if(flag) l++;
        }
        while(l--){
            cout << arr[l];
        }
        if(i != n-1){
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Question statement:
 You are asked to calculate the factorials of some small positive integers.
Input:

An integer n, 1<=n<=100, denoting the number of testcases, followed by n lines, each containing a single integer t, 1<=t<=100.
Output:

For each integer n given at input, display a line with the value of t!

This is working fine for t < 35 but starts giving error for t >= 35.
Also tell me how can I improve my coding style. I am new to coding.

CASE 1
sample input:
2
1
35

actual output:
1
-40427027-3-786144929666651337523200000000

expected output:
1
10333147966386144929666651337523200000000

CASE 2
sample input:
3
5
6
7

actual output:
120
720
5040

expected output:
120
720
5040

PS Sorry!, Initial question changed as I ignored floating point errors while calculating 17! from scientific calculator. Now, code is not working for values greater than 34

Error was in part that rem can be a 3 digit number so diving by 10 doesn't work. Need to take care for rem > 100

Comment: Overflow I would say. `factorial(100)` is around `9.332622e+157`.

Comment: do you know what is the value of `17!` ? Compare that to the maximum value an `int` can hold

Comment: that's why i am using an array and trying to apply basic school algebra to multiply each digit one by one.

Comment: Could you add input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: @TusharSingla [How to debug programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: What output are you getting for 17?  What output are you expecting for 17?

Comment: Instead of sticking everything in `main`, create a function that returns the factorial as a string when given an integer as an argument.  That would make the code much more organized and can be tested more easily.

Comment: And test that function versus known values.

Comment: Why do you expect `t = 18` to be 4 higher from your routine than the mathematical `18!`?

Comment: Also, please put the "sample input" in the program itself.  In other words, set the variables to the known (bad) input -- there is no need for `cin` statements.

Comment: @Jarod42 to avoid overflow I am using arrays to multiply digit by digit

Comment: @TusharSingla *Now, code is not working for values greater than 34* -- Debug your code with 34.  Then debug your code using 35.  What is magic about 35 that doesn't work, but 34 does?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how can I debug my code. Please help me with that.

Comment: @TusharSingla You are not using a compiler on your computer?  If not, get yourself one (they are free of charge now), compile your code, and use the debugger that comes with the compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am using codechef online ide

Comment: You are getting `-` in your output because your multiply-and-carry logic is overflowing (and wrapping around to negative).

Comment: @TusharSingla Look at the comment above: *You are getting - in your output because your multiply-and-carry logic is overflowing (and wrapping around to negative).* -- Which means that you are *not* doing schoolbook math.  You should have a digit-per-array-element.  Thus no overflow possible should be occurring.

Comment: For one iteration of `j`, `l` can only increase of one unity. For `j` higher than 12, you may need more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part of your code looks wrong since it cycles only up to length of your number
so it may grow only by one digit when there is flag:

```
        for(k = 0; k < l; k++){
            int temp = (arr[k]*j) ;
            arr[k] = (temp + rem) % 10;
            rem = (temp+rem) / 10;
            if(k == l-1 && rem != 0){
                arr[l] = rem;
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if(flag) l++;
```

It should be something shorter like:

```
   for(k = 0; k < l; k++) {
        rem += arr[k] * j;
        arr[k] = rem % 10;
        rem /= 10;
        if(k == l-1 && rem != 0) ++l;
    }
```